# AJAX load() not working for table. I have to reload manually

Tags: php, ajax

Everyone.

I've got the following AJAX to load a table:

```
<script>
function loadtable(){
$( '#table1').load('tablerow.php #table1');
}
</script>



<table name="table1" id="table1" class="center" onload="loadtable();">
        
        <tbody>
        <tr><th>DSA #</th><th>Plan</th><th>Initial Plan?</th><th>DDD#</th><th>Program</th><th>Consumer<br>Name</th><th>Coordinator<br>Name</th><th>PEA Upload<br>Date</th><th>DOB</th><th>Plan Approval<br>Date</th><th>DS&A Start<br>Date</th><th>Plan Start<br>Date</th><th>Plan End<br>Date</th><th style="width:100px;">Action</th><th>Link to MTs</th></tr>

        <?php
        $n = 0;
        $mp = 0;
        $id = 0;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($rs))
    {
                include 'tablerow.php'; //this line draws the rows and sets up the $id variable.  tablerow.php does all the heavy lifting.  I use includes instead of other functions here because it keeps the code cleaner, and because my experimentation with HEREDOC showed that it would fragment the file more if  I did it that way.  -- BH
                $id++;
            }
        ?>

        
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

tablerow.php looks like this:

```
<tr>
                <?php
                     
                       error_reporting(E_ALL);
                       ini_set('display_errors', 1);
                       $AD = $row['Approval_Date'];
                       $Program = $row['Program'];
                       $DOB = $row['DOB'];
                       $Plan_Approval_Date = $row['Plan_Approval_Date'];
                       $Last_Name = $row['Last_Name'];
                       $First_Name = $row['First_Name'];
                       $DDD_Case = $row['DDD_Case'];
                       $Initial_Plan = $row['Initial_Plan1'];
                       $Plan = $row['Plan'];
                       $Client_ID = $row['Client_ID'];
                       $DSA_ID = $row['DSA_ID'];
                       $UID = $DDD_Case . "_" . $Plan;
                      

  if (strtotime($row['Plan_Approval_Date']) > strtotime($row['Approval_Date']))
  {
      $Approval_Date = $row['Plan_Approval_Date'];
  }
  else{
      $Approval_Date = $row['Approval_Date'];
  }

if($Approval_Date <> '')
{
    $Plan_End_Date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+364 days', strtotime($Approval_Date)));
}
else
{
    $Plan_End_Date = '';
}
?>              

<script>
    function submitrecord<?php echo $id; ?>()
    { 
        

        pln = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Plan"];  /*   Plan */
        mdate = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Medicaid_Date"];  /*  Medicaid Date */
        prog = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Program"];   /*  Program */
        pad = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Plan_Approval_Date"];  /* Plan Approval Date */
        ip = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Initial_Plan"];  /*  Initial Plan */
        pea = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["PEA_Update"];  /*  PEA Date */
        ad = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Approval_Date"]; /* Plan Start Date */
        ped = document.forms["b<?php echo $id; ?>"]["Plan_End_Date"]; /* Plan Start Date */

var dte = pad.value;
var dt1 = new Date(dte);

var dte2 = ped.value;
var dt2 = new Date(dte2);
//alert(dte);
//alert(dte2);

if(dt2 < dt1){alert("End date is before start date. Please correct this!");
return(1);
}
    


/*  This code checks to see if the Plan number and the Initial Plan status are the same as the database.  If it is, all's clear, and it's submitted.  */


/*  This code checks to see if it's not a CCP-Short and the Program is filled in. */
    //  alert("At least it runs.");

        
        if(prog.value ==''){
            event.preventDefault();alert('Program is blank!  This should not be.');
            return(1);
        }


        if(pad.value ==''){
            event.preventDefault();alert('Plan Approval Date is blank!  This should not be.');
            return(1);
        }
        
        if(ip.value == '1'){
            /*if(mdate.value == '')
                {event.preventDefault();alert('Medicaid Start Date is blank!  This should not be.');
                return(1);}*/

            if(pea.value == '' && (prog.value == 'CCP' || 
               prog.value == 'Supports')) // if PEA date is blank and Program is CCP or Supports
            {
                event.preventDefault();alert('PEA Date is blank!  This should not be.');
                return(1);
            }

            if(pad.value == '')
            {
                event.preventDefault();alert('Plan Approval Date is blank!  This should not be.');
                return(1);
            }

        
        }
        
        if(ip.value == '1'){
            if(prog.value == 'CCP-Short' && ped.value =='')
            {
                event.preventDefault();alert('Plan End Date is blank!  This should not be.');
            }

            if(ad.value == '')
            {
                event.preventDefault();alert('Plan End Date is blank!  This should not be.');
                return(1);
            }


        }

        document.getElementById('b<?php echo $id ?>').submit();
        
        }
    
</script>


                <form id="b<?php echo $id; ?>" method="POST" action="planupdate.php?DSA_ID=<?php echo $DSA_ID; ?>">
                <input id="DSA_ID<?php echo $id;?>" name="DSA_ID" value="<?php echo $DSA_ID; ?>" type="hidden">
                <td><input id="Client_ID<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="5" name="Client_ID" class="Client_ID" value="<?php echo $row['Client_ID']; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input form ="b<?php echo $id; ?>" id="Plan" type="text" name="Plan" size="4" class="Plan" value="<?php echo $row['Plan']; ?>"></td>
                <td><select id="Initial_Plan" name="Initial_Plan" class="Initial_Plan"><option <?php if($Initial_Plan == "0"){echo "Selected ";}; ?> value="0">No</option><option <?php if($Initial_Plan == "1"){echo "Selected ";}; ?> value="1">Yes</option></select></td>
                <td><input id="DDD<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="DDD_Case" class="DDD_Case" value="<?php echo $DDD_Case; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><select required id="Program<?php echo $id; ?>" name="Program" class="Program"><option value = ""></option><option <?php if($Program == "CCP-Short"){echo "Selected ";}; ?>>CCP-Short</option><option <?php if($Program == "CCP"){echo "Selected ";}; ?>>CCP</option><option <?php if($Program == "Interim"){echo "Selected ";}; ?>>Interim</option><option <?php if($Program == "Supports"){echo "Selected ";}; ?>>Supports</option><option <?php if($Program == "E-Record"){echo "Selected ";}; ?>>E-Record</option></select></td>
                <td><?php echo $First_Name . " " . $Last_Name; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['SC_FName'] . " " . $row['SC_LName']; ?></td>
                <td><input id="PEA_Update<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="PEA_Update" class="PEA_Update" value="<?php echo $row['PEA_Update']; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input id="Medicaid_Date<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="DOB" class="DOB" value="<?php echo $row['DOB']; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input id="Plan_Approval_Date<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="Plan_Approval_Date" class="Plan_Approval_Date" value="<?php echo $row['Plan_Approval_Date']; ?>"  readonly></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['Start_Date2']; ?></td>
                <td><input id="Approval_Date<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="Approval_Date" class="Approval_Date" value="<?php echo $AD; ?>" readonly></td>
                <td><input id="Plan_End_Date<?php echo $id; ?>" type="text" size="10" name="Plan_End_Date" class="Plan_End_Date" value="<?php if($row['Plan_End_Date'] <> ''){echo $row['Plan_End_Date'];} else {if($row['Program'] <> 'CCP-Short'){
                    $Plan_End_Date = date('m/d/Y', strtotime('+ 364 days', strtotime($Plan_Approval_Date)));
                    echo $row['Plan_End_Date'];
                }

                }?>"></td>
                <td><input id="tst<?php echo $id; ?>" form="b<?php echo $id; ?>" value="Update Plan" name="Submit" type="submit" onclick="event.preventDefault();submitrecord<?php echo $id; ?>();"></td>
                <td><a href='mtool3-session.php?DDD_Case=<?php echo $DDD_Case; ?>&Plan=<?php echo $row['Plan']; ?>'>Link to MTs</a><?php if($Job_Title == 'Administrator' || $Job_Title == 'Administration Manager'){include 'delform.php';} ?>
</td>
    


</form>
</tr>
```

The problem is, this only works if I reload the page.  If I reload when I hit the page, everything is fine, but without that, the table doesn't show up.  And the success message is never displayed.  I can see the information in the database when I'm done, but the success message never shows up, so I feel like there must be something wrong on the submit end that keeps the information from working correctly, even though it's there.  I assume that's why I have to reload the page.

Can anyone give me any guidance?  Thanks!

Comment: `<table onload="loadtable();">` won’t do anything. You can not slap that event handler attribute on just any arbitrary element, it only fires for window, resp. the body element.

Comment: _“I use includes instead of other functions here because it keeps the code cleaner”_ - so you are worried about clean code in this one particular location, yet you create new JavaScript functions with “numbered names” for each single table row? And btw., your element nesting is invalid, you can not nest a form into a table row like that - the form either has to go around the whole table, or be contained within a single table cell.

Comment: Maybe it's dumb luck, but coding the form that way actually works.  I mean, it might have something to do with the AJAX failing I guess, but I have a version of the page that doesn't use the AJAX, and it submits the page okay.  If you view source on the actual page, it creates the right IDs and the form submits.  But that could have to do with why the code is breaking there in the AJAX submission.  I don't know.

Comment: When I attach the onload event to the body tag, it actually makes things a little worse. The whole table row flashes, but then disappears, no matter how many times I reload the page.

Comment: For now, I solved the problem with a page refresh with a hash when the page loads.